# Работа с дочерними окнами mdiArea в QT

Tags: c++, qt

Создаю дочернее окно в mdiArea и далее хочу вставить туда текст, но как "обратиться" к этому окну - не понимаю. 
Изначально делалось через обычный textEdit и там вопросов не возникало (видно в закомментированной строке).
Вопрос: как вставить текст в дочернее окно mdiArea?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```
 void MainWindow::on_actionopen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open file...", "C:\\Users\\student\\Documents\\", "*.txt");
    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QMdiSubWindow* newWindow = new QMdiSubWindow( ui->mdiArea );
    newWindow->setWidget( new QTextEdit( newWindow ) );
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(newWindow);
    newWindow->setObjectName(fileName);
    newWindow->show();
//    ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow(TextEdit)


    //ui->textEdit->setText(file.readAll());
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращаться надо не к окну, а к самому `QTextEdit`:

```
//...
QTextEdit *te = new QTextEdit( newWindow )
te->setText(file.readAll());
newWindow->setWidget( te );
//...
```